# Why isn't a for-each loop accepting an instance of the Iterable class?

Tags: java

```
Iterable<Position<Integer>> iterable = list.positions();
    Iterator<Position<Integer>> iter = iterable.iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iter.next().getData());
    }
```

The above code works with no issues. `list` is just an instance of a List class that I wrote. It contains elements of the Integer type.

```
        for (Position<Integer> pos : iterable) {

    }
```

This code fails at the part past the colon. This should be equivalent to the first piece of code, the one with the while loop. So I don't understand why the for-each loop has an error. The error says: "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable" - but `iterable` already is Iterable, isn't it? What am I missing here?

the following is the full code implementing the aforementioned methods and types.

```
    private class PositionIterator implements Iterator<Position<E>> {
    private Position<E> cursor = first();
    private Position<E> current = null;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return cursor.getData() != null;
    }

    public Position<E> next() {
        if (cursor == null) throw new NoSuchElementException("reached the end of the list");
        current = cursor;
        cursor = after(cursor);
        return current;
    }
}

private class PositionIterable implements Iterable<Position<E>> {
    public Iterator<Position<E>> iterator() {
        return new PositionIterator();
    }
}

public Iterable<Position<E>> positions() {
    return new PositionIterable();
}
```

these are nested classes within another class called `PositionalList<E>`. In the interest of keeping this post compact, I decided to omit the outside class. It's just a bunch of getter and setter methods that are typical for a List class.

```
public interface Iterable<E> {
    public Iterator<E> iterator();
}
```

^that's the Iterable interface being implemented by `PositionIterable`

```
public interface Iterator<E> {
    boolean hasNext();
    E next();
}
```

^And that's the `Iterator` interface.

Comment: Is it possible you created your own class called Iterable which hides java.util.Iterable? Please post the complete code that doesn't work.

Comment: Eran, yes, I did. Not exactly an Iterable class, but an interface. I then created a class that implements Iterable. Will edit main post with a copy of the code in a sec

Comment: Why do you overwrite an existing JDK interface?

Comment: So what happens if you use `implements java.lang.Iterable` instead of your own version?

Comment: Tichodroma, it's for a homework assignment asking me to specifically implement my own interfaces and classes.

Comment: So, you're using your own interface and then you wonder, why the enhanced for loop won't accept it?

Comment: @JoD., haven't tried that yet, but one of the requirements for this (my) assignment is to implement my own interfaces. Even if it works, I can't do it that way. Also, I've written the classes and interfaces almost word-for-word from examples in the textbook I'm using, yet somehow i'm getting errors. I want to find out why.

Comment: @Tom yeap, exactly that.

Comment: Well you cannot invent your own interface. It *has* to be `java.lang.Iterable` for the enhanced for loop to work. See [oracle blog on enhanced for loop](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with)

Comment: @JoD. Yup, just figured that out by reading the other comments pointing out the same problem. I had no idea it had to be done that way. I guess also I misinterpreted my assignment a bit. Can't believe all the hours wasted trying to get this to work!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The enhanced for loop accepts an `Iterable`, not an `Iterator`. `iter` is an `Iterator`.

Therefore :

```
for (Position<Integer> pos : iter)
```

Should be :

```
for (Position<Integer> pos : iterable)
```

EDIT : Based on the comments, your problem must be hiding `java.lang.Iterable` by your custom `Iterable` interface. If your `iterable` variable is of the type of your custom `Iterable` interface, it can't be used by the enhanced for loop, which accepts `java.lang.Iterable`.

Comment: hey, yeah sorry about that typo. I really meant iterable. I'm still getting the same error, though.

Comment: I think you mean `java.lang.Iterable`.  Apart from that, spot on.

Comment: Really? So the enhanced for loop accepts only java.lang.Iterable? Huh, so the error message was literally telling me the answer all along... good to know.

Comment: @MannyKim What do you mean by "overwrites"? If you require a custom Iterable interface, you can always extend `java.lang.Iterable`, and this way your interface would still work with the enhanced for loop.

Comment: @Eran thanks! I don't know why I hadn't thought of that. That's great.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have any issues running that code.  Here's my local test code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Iterable<String> iterable = Arrays.asList("foo",
                                              "bar");
    for (String anIterable : iterable)
    {
        System.out.println(anIterable);
    }
}
```

If you have created a local class or interface called Iterable, that's the only reason I could think why this wouldn't work.  If you have done that, delete it and then maybe go back and review the purpose of interfaces too.

Comment: But why wouldn't it work with my own implementation? What have I done wrong?

Comment: The answer is in your original comment: "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable".  What package does your Iterable class have? The main problem, however, is that you don't need to define anything with a java.* package - you get these from Java itself.  **Think of it like this:** if you create a class or an interface, the package name should be that of your organisation or project. This will prevent issues like this happening again for you.

Comment: Thank you very much, Steve! I had no idea that the error was specifically referring to java.lang.Iterable. I guess I wasn't reading that line right. I thought it included all custom Iterable classes and interfaces